# Identification of scientists in de Gennes book

Tags: physics, biographical-details, scientists

*Petit Point: A Candid Portrait on the Aberrations of Science* is a charming book written by the French physicist Pierre-Gilles de Gennes containing short essays on some of the prominent scientists that he encountered in his career. For obvious reasons, their names have been replaced with pseudonyms.

I list the chapter names from the book: Mastoc, Vera, Lanterne, Leduc, Emmy, Breton, Smirnoff, Pluvieux, Beziers, Kuba, Vladimir, Aglae, Subtil, Chazot, Anchor, Croesus, Caesar, Guru, Dourakine, Saplir, Manfred, Robert, Polymorph, Revizor, Feston, Philostrate, Elise, Spiros, Akbar

The scientists I could identify: Caesar - Benoit Mandelbrot, Manfred - Brian Josephson, Subtil - Bernd Matthias, Chazot - Per Bak.

Other potential candidates: Robert - de Gennes himself, Emmy - Susan Coppersmith

Could someone identify the remaining names listed ? Thanks

Comment: How did you identify the others?

Comment: Some were obvious from their peculiar traits/life histories